# According to Isamic Sharia, what should a husband do?

Tags: nikah

According to Isamic Sharia, given that the husband feels that he has enough grounds** to marry a second time, what should he do if the first wife threatens to kill herself?

<sub>**The husband is a scientific researcher, and the first wife has an aversion toward study. So, the husband feels that he has become a cart with uneven wheels.</sub>